# .net core new project template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When I create a new .net core project I expect to see a 'src' folder with my solution. However when I create new project I get the following setup.

[image: wrong template]

I've already tried to de-install eand install the SDK again. 
And furthermore I'm also having trouble to restore some nuget packages. Then I get the error (in output): Object reference is not set to an instance.

That makes me think there is something wrong with my setup, however I cannot find what it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: You try to run a VisualStudio as an administrator

Comment: if you do `File-->New-->Project-->Templates-->.Net Core -> ASP.Net Core Web Application`  you should see `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you do `File-->New-->Project-->Templates-->.Net Core -> ASP.Net Core Web Application`  you should see `src` folder.

You need to have  .net 1.0 SDK  and .net 1.0 tooling for VS 2015 installed.

[image]

Comment: I do have this option, but it seems there is a different template. I get no src-folder.